# PHP: MySQL Module Missing

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

On Ubuntu 16, `dpkg --list` showing the following:

```
root@srv# dpkg --list | grep -i php
rc  php7.1-mysql                      7.1.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1                    amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

When I try to install it via apt, I get:

```
root@srv# apt install php7.1-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php7.1-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php7.1-mysql' has no installation candidate
```

also installing `php-mysql` did not help as the server has multiple php versions already installed:

```
root@srv# apt-get install php-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-mysql : Depends: php7.0-mysql but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

any advice?

Comment: The `mysql` extension was removed in PHP 7.0. You should use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I am using some legacy code that require `mysql`, changing to PDO or mysqli require way more work and shall be done later

Comment: There's a shim for emulating mysql with mysqli. https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim

Comment: Not having access to code either composer tight me to have `mysql`

Comment: PHP 7.1 is horribly outdated and should no longer be used since years